# How to configure Python to ignore the hostname verification?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl

We are relatively new to in Python therefore may be the question is too simple.
We are using Python version 2.7.15.

We are trying to use Python over TLS without success.

This is our code:

```
import ssl,socket
import urllib2

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = False
context.load_verify_locations("/py-test/python/bin/certificate.pem")
url = "https://10.0.0.12"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
websocket = urllib2.urlopen(request,None,None,None,None,None,context)
pages=websocket.readlines()
print pages
```

As you see, we have configured `context.check_hostname = False`

Unfortunately, it fails with the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
   websocket = urllib2.urlopen(request,None,None,None,None,None,context)
 File "/py-test/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
   return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "/py-test/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
   response = self._open(req, data)
 File "/py-test/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
   '_open', req)
 File "/py-test/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
   result = func(*args)
 File "/py-test/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
   context=self._context)
 File "/py-test/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
   raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)>
```

It is definitely the hostname verification.
If we use the correct certificate and correct hostname the request successful.

If we use the wrong certificate it fails with the following exception.

```
File "./test.py", line 8, in <module>
   context.load_verify_locations("/py-test/python/bin/certificate_bad.pem")
ssl.SSLError: [X509] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3027)
```

Therefore, we need help to understand how to configure Python to ignore the hostname verification.

One more question (can be asked in the separate thread).

Do we have in Python a trustore file that include all known CA? Like `cacerts.jks` in Java.
Where can we find the trustore?

**Added**

We “want to verify that the certificate was signed by a valid CA”, but we “don't care whether it identifies the site you're actually connecting to”.

We need help to configure Python to ignore the hostname verification?
What is mistake in our code?
We have tried to create the code according to the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html

**Added 2**

We have invested a lot of time but unfortunately we do not have the progress.

Is anyone has the working example in Python 2.7?
I mean is the code works if you access with other URL then appears in a certificate.
May be Python 2.7 cannot be configured to ignore the hostname verification?

What can be our problem?
We use it on CentOS 6.
May be it is related to OpenSSL? We use the latest version openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64.
May be we should upgrade to Python 3.x?

Comment: Not an answer to your direct question, but to your indirect one: You want the [`certifi`](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) package. It's included by default with `requests` which is a popular HTTP client library for Python. And, I should probably mention: it's 2019. Python 2.7 is scheduled for end-of-life in less than a year. If you're "relatively new" to Python, it might be good to start with a newer version now rather than dealing with the upgrade later.

Comment: Just so I understand: your question is that you *want to verify that the certificate was signed by a valid CA*, but you *don't care whether it identifies the site you're actually connecting to*? Why would you want that? Security-wise, it's completely equivalent to trusting a self-signed certificate.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden, thanks for `certifi`. We have not started with Python 2.7. We have found Python in one of the legacy modules and now we need to learn to work with it.  Yes, we “want to verify that the certificate was signed by a valid CA”, but we “don't care whether it identifies the site you're actually connecting to”. 
Yes, we agree that it is “completely equivalent to trusting a self-signed certificate”.
Do you know how to configure Python to ignore the hostname verification?
We have tried to create the code according to the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html

Comment: I remember `requests` package in `python 2.7` allows a workaround for self-signed CA using environmental variables, that still goes through a white-list to match them. It's buried somewhere in the documentations.

Answer (score 4):

As you discovered, you can accomplish this by customizing the `SSLContext` object used for verifying the connection.

However, to hook this into `urllib2.urlopen` you'll need to build a custom opener and install that.

Here's an example:

```
import httplib
import socket
import ssl
import urllib2

import certifi


class InterceptedHttpsConnection(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
    def connect(self):
        # Open an unencrypted TCP socket first
        sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)

        # Build up a custom SSLContext. (Might be better to do this once rather
        # than on every request.)
        context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)

        # We require the SSL context to verify the certificate.
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED

        # But we instruct the SSL context to *not* validate the hostname.
        context.check_hostname = False

        # Load CA certificates from the certifi bundle.
        context.load_verify_locations(cafile=certifi.where())

        # Use our SSLContext object to wrap the bare socket into an SSL socket.
        self.sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)


class InterceptedHttpsHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def https_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(InterceptedHttpsConnection, req)


def main():
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(InterceptedHttpsHandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    contents = urllib2.urlopen('https://example.com/').read()
    print contents
```

Comment: We have invested a lot of time but unfortunately we do not have the progress.
Is this example works in your environment in version 2.7?
I mean is the code works if you access with other URL then appears in a certificate.
What can be our problem?
We use it on CentOS 6.
May be it is related to OpenSSL? We use the latest version.
May be we should upgrade to python 3.x?

Comment: Is your example works in your environment in version 2.7? I mean is the code works if you access with other URL then appears in a certificate.

Comment: I thought I had tested to confirm it works, but I don't have a set up right now that makes it easy to verify. However: if you're hooking the socket creation, you can also fake the value passed to the `server_hostname` argument of the `wrap_socket` method. That might be enough to resolve your problem.

Comment: We have found the problem and looks like your example was correct.
I will not accept any answer till the bounty will be divided between 2 answers. 
Then I will accept you answer (you have provided more info).

Answer (score 3):

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Forces python to skip the validation of certificates by default. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks!
But we *need* to validate the trust of certificates and therefore `ssl._create_unverified_context` not good for us.
We need to ignore the hostname verification.
Do you know how to configure Python to ignore the hostname verification?

Comment: ssl._https_verify_certificates(enable=False)

Better solution is to upgrade to python3, but barring that, requests lets you use some of its features in python2.

Comment: We have found the problem and looks like your example was correct.
I will not accept any answer till the bounty will be divided between 2 answers. 
Then I will accept other answer (he has provided more info).